# Failing to restore the state - App terminates after giving SFEffectCache:clear() error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

When I launch the camera from an activity for results, sometimes the app just terminates without indicating anything. After looking at logcat on these scenarios, I could find the following error.

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear()
```

So far, this was occurred in samsung devices (Note 2 and S5) and only when using the camera.

I have handled savedInstance through `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. When this happens `onRestoreInstanceState()` never gets called.

This question has been asked in many occasions, but I couldn't find a proper answer.